# Not able to connect Phone gap mobile to phone gap desktop

Tags: android, cordova, apk, phonegap-desktop-app

I am very new in Apps development. I wanted to learn Apps development & i got to know about **phone gap** as app development tool.

I followed this url: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/307

```
Till 7 step i'm fine but after then i am stuck.
```

I am not able to connect my mobile to desktop app. **It's  saying unable to download archive from server.**

I have mobile & PC connected in same WIFI. What else i have to do?

Please help

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to download from the browser in your mobile device?

Comment: yes i tried but its saying couldn't load this page.

Comment: It seems mobile & laptop are not in same network. But they are connected in same WIFI. Anything else i have to do to make it in same network or any other issue please help.